# How to use ArduinoJson with SD.h library

Tags: c, nodemcu, arduino-c++

I use ArduinoJson to parse Sensor Data from two Sensors from Arduino Uno to nodemcu ESP8266. This worked pretty well until I installed the SD.h library in the Code of the Arduino. I need it because it is necessary to  save the data also on the SD Card. When I use this library now on my code I got only two Datas on the Serial Monitor. It should be a continuous output of data. I checked, when I delete the`serializeJson(doc, nodemcu);` line, I got all the datas.
What can I do to parse data with ArduinoJson and use also the SD.h library ?

Here's the code of the Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

SoftwareSerial nodemcu(5, 6);

float emg1, emg2, emgdiff;


char filename1[30];
char filename2[30];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
   nodemcu.begin(4800);
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {
  StaticJsonDocument<1000> doc;
  float sensorValue01 = analogRead(A0);
  float sensorValue02 = analogRead(A1);


  emg1 = sensorValue01/1023 * 5;
  emg2 = sensorValue02/1023 * 5;
  emgdiff = emg1 - emg2;
  Serial.println(emg1);
  Serial.println(emg2);

   doc["emg1"] = emg1;
   doc["emg2"] = emg2;
  serializeJson(doc, nodemcu);
}
```

Comment: you run out of memory. do you really need 1000 bytes for the JSON?

Comment: Do you really need to use serializeJson at all? If all you need to do is save the values to the SD card as a CSV. It should be far less memory intensive and that way you can use the same file over and over on the SD card without ever having to read it back in.